# best way of searching string in sql table column of type "nvarchar(max)"

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

i'm trying to search within a table like [image]

which works fine and gives a result table.
Also works fine if i searched like 
[image]
But if added a digit before "ND" like

```
set @n='2 ND'
```

[image]

the search doesn't yield a result.
can anybody help??
Thanks in advance

Comment: do u have `2 nd` in ur column?

Comment: @MuhammadQasim yes ,please see the result in the first image

Comment: no image is shown. can your show some sample data?

Comment: @pavankumar It should work, just check the number of spaces between `2` and `N` in both name column value and  `@n` value. Make sure the number of spaces between `2` and `N` is same in both the places.

Comment: the sample data looks like `2  ND` has 2 spaces between the values so it won't find it. Try changing your search to have 2 spaces and see if it works: `SET @n = '2  ND'`

Comment: @JibinBalachandran thanks my friend ,it worked there are extra spaces between '2' and 'ND' ,but when the names are taken to a webpage all the spaces are not being displayed as is

Comment: @pavankumar don't ask for votes, the question is pretty bad, as it is just a typo problem, so it's not going to be useful for anyone but you. Plus you pasted images instead of actual code that we could have copied and pasted.

Comment: @pavankumar Ya, html will trim the extra spaces while displaying. If you inspect the component you can see the extra spaces.I'm glad that your issue is resolved.

Comment: Also, this question should now be closed as it can no longer be reproduced / simple typographical problem.

Comment: @Tanner i could've pasted the code but it wouldn't work because you don't have the database which i'm working on,it seems the images made sense to everyone else but you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to your image, you appear to have two spaces between the "2" and "nd".  So start by trying:

```
set @n = '2  ND';
```

Next, the spaces may not be ASCII spaces.  If the above doesn't work, try the following, in order:

```
set @n = '2%ND';
set @n = '2__ND';
set @n = '2_ND';
```

The first should definitely match.  The second would match two characters.  The third would match a single character.  If you do find that spaces don't match but the wildcard does, you can investigate what characters are actually in the data.

Comment: thanks my friend,extra spaces are the issue here.In this case there are 2 spaces rather than 1 as i presumed